# HTML CANVAS with text inside

Tags: html, canvas

Is it possible to element canvas  put text or icons.
For example:

```
<canvas id="hexmap" width="200" height="200">
    <img src="facebook.png" />
</canvas>
```

I want to create hexagon container and the insert icons or text.
Sorry for my English

Answer (score 3):

To draw an image, you don't wrap img elements inside a canvas element like you do in html.

Instead, Html Canvas is a drawing surface.

You issue drawing commands and pixels will be drawn on the canvas.

A Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/qwy5x/

[image]

To draw an image on the canvas, you do:

```
// draw yourImage at xy=[20,20]

context.drawImage(yourImage,20,20);
```

To draw text on the canvas, you do:

```
// draw "Hello World" at xy=[20,20]

context.fillText("Hello World",20,20);
```

There are many drawing commands:

- drawImage,
- fillText,
- moveTo,
- lineTo,
- rect,
- arc,
- etc...

A hexagon is a six-sided regular polygon.

Here's how to draw a hexagon on an html canvas using drawing commands and a little math:

```
function drawHexagon(cx,cy,size,centerX,centerY){
    var sideCount=6;  // hexagon
    var PI=Math.PI;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(cx+size*Math.cos(0), cy+size*Math.sin(0));          
    for (var i = 1; i <= sideCount;i += 1) {
        var r=i*2*PI/sideCount;
        var x=parseInt(cx+size*Math.cos(r));
        var y=parseInt(cy+size*Math.sin(r));
        ctx.lineTo(x,y);
    }
    ctx.fillStyle="blue";
    ctx.strokeStyle="gray";
    ctx.lineWidth=2;
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fill();  
}
```

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions. Thanks for appreciating my effort...I try to give clear answers.